# requirejs optimizer - how to change the optimized module name

Tags: gulp, requirejs, requirejs-optimizer

I want to optimize some modules with the requirejs optimizer, but ran into a problem concerning paths. The `main.js` entry point requires the component on `/build/modules/`, but the name of the optimized module does not match this path. The component file is loaded, but the function it defines isn't called.
`main_component.js` requires the components `moduleA` and `moduleB`, and the `build`'s `main.js` requires the built `main_component.js`.

Code of `./build/main.js`:

```
require(['./modules/main_component'], function () {
  console.log('main')
})
```

Code of `./build/modules/main_component`:

```
/* component definitions ... */
define('main_component',
    ['require','components/moduleA','components/moduleB'],
    function (require) { /* ... */}
)
```

Project structure:

```
/
|-- build
|   |-- modules
|   |   +-- main_component.js # optimized file
|   +-- main.js
|-- js
|   +-- modules
|       |-- components
|       |   |-- moduleA.js
|       |   +-- moduleB.js
|       +-- main_component.js
+-- index.html
```

Also, I'm using a gulp wrapper `gulp-requirejs-optimize`. This is my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var requirejsOptimize = require('gulp-requirejs-optimize')

gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('js/modules/*.js')
    .pipe(requirejsOptimize({
      optimize: 'none'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/modules'))
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `skipDirOptimize: true` to the `requirejsOptimize` options did the trick. As per the [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#wholemultipage):

> If doing a whole project optimization, but only want to minify the build layers specified in modules options and not the rest of the JS files in the build output directory, you can set skipDirOptimize to true.